# A question about punctuation

Tags: punctuation

Every man chased three deer going to the forest while eating oranges.

Every man chased three deer going to the forest, while eating oranges.

Does the comma greatly alter the meaning of the second sentence when compared with the first sentence?

Comment: No, both versions are ambiguous. The second makes it slightly more likely that the correct interpretation is that the men (and not the deer) were eating oranges. And they're also ambiguous as to whether there were three deer, or three deer for every man.

Comment: There comes a point where clumsiness and nonsensicalness make a grammatical and conventionally punctuated sentence unacceptable.

Comment: Don't you think you'd find more suitable help at SE Writing, or even English Language Learners?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the meaning of "while". if "while" is meant as "at the same time", you shouldn't use a comma. If "while" means "whereas" or "although", you should use a comma.

In your example, the "while" is used as "at the same time", so no, no comma needed here :)

Comment: But doesn't the comma help to distinguish the referent of 'while eating oranges'? The men or the deer? // I'm leaving this question now as I consider the examples ill-chosen.

Comment: I thank you all for your responses.Want to add this bit also: Peter Shor and Edwin Ashworth, the two of you seem to be on the same wavelength regarding this question, but Cyhiraeth offers a slightly different perspective---How relevant is that? :)

Comment: Sorry about choosing such clunky examples.But since my point is only to have the "Comma Version" differentiated from the "Non-comma Version", I didn't give choosing appropriate examples a think.Still to stave off any shred of further ambiguity, there are three deer for each man.And what Edwin Ashworth mentioned in his last comment is what I precisely want to know: Does using comma change the referent of " while eating oranges" ? Or is it the men who are eating oranges in both cases---and comma simply is redundant?

Comment: And what if I altogether drop 'While' from the two versions? Are the sentences still grammatically and semantically sound?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the referent of the orange eaters completely unambiguous, reverse the components:

> While eating oranges, every man chased three deer going to the forest.

Note, however, that this isn't so much about the comma itself (or punctuation in general), but about the location of the dependent clause.

Comment: Thank you, Jason Bassford :) Your version is sleeker than mine. However, my purpose here was more to know about the effect placing a comma has on the given sentence.Still a modicum of doubt lingers: What about this version of the same sentence-----Every man chased three deer going to the forest, eating oranges?

Comment: That version is also ambiguous. The effect of the comma doesn't alter the *possible* ambiguity; it only alters the commonly perceived ambiguity. Using a comma still results in ambiguity, although it's more *likely* it won't be misinterpreted.

Comment: Got it.Thanks! :)